# How to devide div with number and give resoult valute as a font size

Tags: javascript, css

I made dynamically div and H2, so now I want to h2 size is equal DIV-width / 20, so that means if div width is 400px, font size should be 20px. 
So here is what i did:

```
var div2 = document.createElement('div');  
div2.className = "div2" ;  
div2.id = "div2";
var h2 = document.createElement('h2');
h2.innerHTML= "GET AN ESTIMATE OVER VIDEO CHAT";
h2.className = "naslov";

var DivWidtx = document.getElementById("div2").getBoundingClientRect().width;
    alert(DivWidtx); // - this is working good
    var fontSize = DivWidtx / 20;
    alert(fontSize);
```

So this script does not working, can someone help me how to do it? 

 So I want divWidth / 20 = fontSize, and H2 { font-size = fontSize; }
    h2.style.fontSize = fontSize;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
var fontSize = (parseInt(DivWidtx) / 20 ) + 'px';
```

instead this:

```
var fontSize = (DivWidtx / 20) ;
```

Comment: That is it, I just miss that parseInt. Thank you.